# Datatables: How to search table row for string and hide row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Row Content Sample: (this content is loaded from a json array txt file)

```
<div class='debug'><a href='/DH033368-4041-SR-0910-00005-006-0-CPC-20131105-1652/debug/DH033368-4041-SR-0910-000-Stage 1B Client Review-filteredCommentsXFDF.xml' target='_blank'>[webdav]</a> : /Company Home/filteredCommentsXFDF.xml</div>
```

I need to either find the debug class within a DataTable row(s) or search for '/debug/' in the "href" attribute and if found hide the row.

Javascript is not my strong suite. Any help is appreciated.

What I have so far:

```
        $("#hide").click(function() {
            console.log('HIDE');
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
              function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                  return        $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).data().search("/debug/");
                }
            );
            table.draw();
        });    
        $("#reset").click(function() {
            console.log('RESET');
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
            table.draw();
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: need a little more info. If you are searching for the debug class, its as simple as var found = $(".debug").  to find the anchor with debug in href it would look more like $("a[href*='/debug/']")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/to$()) to convert the row node to a jQuery instance. This is more easy to work with. Then simply test the `<div>` and the `<a>` `href` for the desired matches :

```js
$('#hide').click(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var $row = table.row(dataIndex).nodes().to$();
    return $row.find('div').hasClass('debug') || 
           $row.find('a').attr('href').indexOf('/debug/')>-1
  })  
  table.draw()
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3co6Lvkx/**

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. :)